# multiple pageview inside multipledimension scroll for Android

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

Hello i need to create multiple scrollview with multiple viewpagers.

I have tried replace viewpages with HorizontalScroll and insert inside it LinearLayout, but still the scrolling is blocked when i have 2 dimensional scrolling.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]